# Question about silo project in Dust

Tags: hugh-howey, wool

In Dust, the most recent installment of the Silo Saga, Donald and his sister use a drone to discover that the Earth outside the immediate area of the 50 silos is not destroyed and is in fact green and full of life.

Was the rest of the Earth never actually destroyed in the same fashion as the land surrounding the silos? Is that why a cleaning released more nanos into the air around the silos (the residents were led to believe that this gas was argon)? To keep the immediate area looking desolate and discourage people from leaving?

And if the above is true, and if the purpose of the silo project was to serve as a time machine so that one of the silos could begin repopulating the Earth after the nanos in the air died out, why would Sen. Thurman plan to keep the silo project going for another 250 years? The residents of silo 17 make it out and the air is fine and they are presumably the only humans left on earth (other than those still in silos) - so why was the project ongoing? Wouldn't Thurman have picked the highest scoring silo, had them drill their way out, and then blown everyone else up?

Answer (score 2):

My take on this was that the whole project had been meticulously planned out in advance and the length of time the silos would operate for had been predetermined, so Thurman and all the others are just "sticking to the plan" even though Thurman definitely knows that the air is ok outside (as he appears without a mask on at one point).

Answer (score 2):

*Was the rest of the Earth never actually destroyed in the same fashion as the land surrounding the silos? Is that why a cleaning released more nanos into the air around the silos (the residents were led to believe that this gas was argon)? To keep the immediate area looking desolate and discourage people from leaving?*

- Yes, all the Earth was destroyed. But as the bad nanos effect doesn't last forever, they had to release, from time to time, some other bad nanos in the atmosphere. They might have predicted that statisticaly, from all 50 silo, there will have someone that does something bad enough to be ban outside. So they use the argon excuse to release more nanos to maintain the desolation of the area.

*Why would Sen. Thurman plan to keep the silo project going for another 250 years?*

- The project is to know what is the best seed for a new mankind. So they needed to know what silo has proven to be the best during generations over years. The servers gathers statistics over years, maybe about discipline, self control, obedience... they thought the sons of the best silo would be the best candidates to rebuilt Earth.

*The residents of silo 17 make it out and the air is fine and they are presumably the only humans left on earth (other than those still in silos) - so why was the project ongoing? Wouldn't Thurman have picked the highest scoring silo, had them drill their way out, and then blown everyone else up?*

- When the Silo 17 residents (mostly ex-18), the Silo 1 had been destroyed by Donald, so Thurman doesn't have any control on the project anymore. We don't know what will happen to the other silos.